# Swift, UISearchBar multiple issue while click

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

[image]

I am having two issues. When I am clicking on search bar background is not covering proper view with top Space.And Cancel button comes only first time when i am click on search bar.If I will click second time cancel button disappear.
have attached the Snapshot too.

**below is my code**

**In viewDidLoad**

```
    self.contactsTableView.delegate = self
    self.contactsTableView.dataSource = self
    self.resultSearchController = ({

            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.searchBar.delegate = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

            self.contactsTableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
            return controller
        })()

    self.contactsTableView.reloadData()


    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, searchBar.frame.width, 44)
        searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        searchBar.backgroundColor = self.utility.uicolorFromHex(0x63003C)
        searchBar.barTintColor = self.utility.uicolorFromHex(0x63003C)

    }

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
          searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
          searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
          searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
          searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
```

Have included UISearchBar Controller by code not by storyboard.
Can Someone please help me on this?

Comment: Does anyone has some solutions?